# Best method to find element which throws exception in ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, exception, dictionary

I have a list of items which is populated by some larger configuration file.

```
List<TextEntrtry> localTextEntries;
```

with elements of type TextEntry:

```
 public class TextEntry
 {
    public Guid Id { get;  set; }
    ....
```

This list is converted to a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Guid, TextEntry> textEntries;
```

and this line throws an exception 'Element with same key already exists':

```
 textEntries = localTextEntries.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
```

Obviously my list contains two elements with the same Id.

My question: what is the best way to find out which elements cause the exception?

(Which would allow me to produce a meaningfull error message)

Comment: Can't you check on debug?

Comment: where is the code that converts this list to dictionary?

Comment: @evilone See my last code snippet: `localTextEntries.ToDictionary()`

Comment: Why not use hashset?

Comment: @Gilad its part of a larger, older library. I can add error handling but can't change the design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-write `ToDictionary` to use your own implementation that includes the `key` in the exception message:

```
//TODO come up with a slightly better name
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> MyToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        try
        {
            dictionary.Add(key, valueSelector(item));
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Missing key: " + key, ex);
        }
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

You'd want to create overloads without a comparer or value selector, in which default values for those parameters are used.

You may also want to create a new type of `Exception` that stores the key as a property, rather than including the string value of the key in the exception message (in the event there is no good string representation of the object).

Answer (score 2):

Run this on your collection to get the ones with duplicate entries:

```
var duplicateEntries = localTextEntries.GroupBy(k = > k.Id)
    .Where(g = > g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g = > g.Key);
```

You can also always add an extension method and get distinct values from your source

```
IEnumerable <TextEntry> distinctList = localTextEntries.DistinctBy(x = > x.Id);

public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinctify<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> inSrc_, Func<TSource, TKey> keyFunct_)
{
    var uniqueSet = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return inSrc_.Where(tmp => uniqueSet.Add(keyFunct_(tmp)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to check for repeated or not repeated items. To create the dictionary run the `ToDictionary` method on the grouped items:

```
// get repeated items
var repeated = localTextEntries.GroupBy(t => t.Id).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(i => i);

// get not repeated items
var notRepeated = localTextEntries.GroupBy(t => t.Id).Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(i => i.First());

// find not repeated items and create a dictionary
var dictFromNotRepeated = localTextEntries.GroupBy(t => t.Id)
            .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the approach of @Servy worked best for me. I just chose a matching overload and added some better error handling:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary2<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    Dictionary<TKey, TSource> dictionary = 
        new Dictionary<TKey, TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        try
        {
            dictionary.Add(key, item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = string.Format("Problems with key {0} value {1}",
                key,
                item);
            throw new Exception(msg, ex);
        }
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```